# How to make MUI's Autocomplete display the label from the matching value in props.options?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a multilingual website where there are certain Autocompletes whose options array need to have its items labels translated, which is done very easily.

However, it would be harder to update the current chosen value, stored elsewhere. Since Autocomplete uses the label from the value prop instead of using the item of same ID within options, it ends up like this:

[image]

```
const vehicles = [
  { id: 1, label: "Car" },
  { id: 2, label: "Bus" }
];

const currentVehicleValue = {
  id: 2,
  label: "Ônibus"
};

export default function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={vehicles}
      value={currentVehicleValue}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Vehicle" />}
    />
  );
}
```

Is there a way to just tell Autocomplete to use the label inside the options prop instead of the one within the value

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-e0wdw9?file=/demo.tsx)

**EDIT:** I mean to have the label within options being shown while I don't type anything. As in, the language changed, the options were translated, but the currentValue was not, so it would be nice to have the Autocomplete use the label from the matching item within options as long as I don't type anything.

Comment: How are the value props gotten? Do you hard code them or are they translated dynamically?

Comment: @Youzef the options are updated by the Autocomplete components that represent one type of data, e.g. VehiclesAutocomplete. The current value is stored in a state that gets its value from the submission of a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit after clarification

You can change how the `<TextField/>` is rendered by tweaking the `props` it receives.

In the example below, I find the `currentVehicle` by its `id` and change the `inputProps.value` to be the vehicle label.

Also, to ensure MUI finds the currentValue correctly within the options, you will need to use the `isOptionEqualToValue` to compare the options ids instead of strict equality

```js
const vehicles = [
  { id: 1, label: "Car" },
  { id: 2, label: "Bus" }
];

const currentVehicleValue = {
  id: 2,
  label: "Ônibus"
};

function compareValueToOption(option, value) {
  return option.id === value.id;
}

function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={vehicles}
      value={currentVehicleValue}
      renderInput={ComboBoxInput}
      isOptionEqualToValue={compareValueToOption}
    />
  );
}

function ComboBoxInput(props) {
  const currentVehicle = vehicles.find(
    (vehicle) => vehicle.id === currentVehicleValue.id
  );
  props.inputProps.value = currentVehicle.label;

  return <TextField {...props} label="Vehicle" />;
}
```

Here's a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-custom-filter-ojiq25?file=/demo.jsx:162-702)

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't explain enough. My goal is that, as long as I don't type anything, the value passed as a prop should be ignored except for the ID, which would be used to display the label of the matching item within options.

Comment: That's OK.

Checkout the answer demo again, I think I got what you need.

Comment: I'm worried about more generic cases and Freesolo, but I think there isn't much escaping doing this. I think this solves my problem.